# JaxRs Client doesn't execute MessageBodyReader

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, jersey-2.0, java-ee-7

I have a problem with setting **MessageBodyReader** - I tried to set it according to a number of tutorials, however its functions are never called. I am using **Jersey 2.27**

This is my MessageBodyReader implementation:

```
@Provider
public class MyMsgBodyReader implements MessageBodyReader<Object> {

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object readFrom(Class<Object> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        HashMap<String, String> hash = new HashMap<>();
        hash.put("replaced", "true");
        return hash;
    }

}
```

And i try to call it like this:

```
@Path("api")
@ApplicationScoped
public class TestClazz {

    @GET
    @Path("test")
    public Response test() {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(MyMsgBodyReader.class).build();
        WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:3000").path("/api/test");
        Response resp = target.request().get();
        Object receivedEntity = resp.getEntity();
        return Response.ok(receivedEntity).build();
    }
}
```

While receivedEntity should be hashmap with one entry, it is still the original entity I received from my test api. I even tried to set breakpoints inside of MyMsgBodyReader methods, and confirmed they are not called even once.

I also tried scanning for it in multiple ways:

```
@ApplicationPath("v1")
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(MyMsgBodyReader.class);
        classes.add(
        return classes;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<>();
        singletons.add(new MsgBodiReader());
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

I don't know what else to try.

Comment: I would suggest you enable jersey tracing, and see if that shows anything. The only other thing of ... you don't have a @Consumes annotation ...

Comment: I also tried to use @Consumes with same result, i'll look into jersey tracing though

Comment: I have to admit, the part that I dont understand is: where is your @Path or resource definition? Such readers kick in *before* content is passed to a resource ... in other words: please consider putting up a real [mcve] here!

Comment: i omitted it for clarity, i edited code now to contain that as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you need to decide is what type of data the reader will handle. You do this with the `@Consumes` annotation. You put this on top of the reader class. Based on the `Content-Type` of the response, Jersey will select the correct reader(s) that matches the media type in the `@Consumes`. If there are multiple readers that match, then the next step is to test the `isReadable()` method. If more than one pass this check, then Jersey will check the priority. You can add a `@Priority(int)` annotation on the reader. Or you can pass the priority as a second argument to the `register()` method.  The higher priority will have the most precedence. If you are using a media type in the `@Consumes` for which there is already a standard reader, then you probably will want to use the `@Priority` so that yours will be used.

If the reader is still not called, you should check the [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) of the response and make sure it is what you expect. You might also set the [`Accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) header (which can be implicitly set by passing a media type to the `request()` method.

Here is an example for which your reader *would* be called.

```
@Provider
@Conumes("application/custom")
public class MyReader implements MessageBodyReader<String> {
}

Response res = client.target("test")
        .register(MyReader.class)
        .request("application/custom")
        .get();
```

Assuming that the server *does* return data of type `application/custom`, this reader should be called. If the server is not capable of returning the data format, and you request that type, then you should get a [406 Not Acceptable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406) error.

Also you should not get the returned data with `Response#getEntity()`. You should use `readEntity(Class)`, passing in the Java type you want the data converted to (uses `MessageBodyReader` under the hood). And for generics, you should use `GenericType`

```
Map<String, String> data = res.readEntity(new GenericType<Map<String, String>>(){});
```

Here's a complete test using [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/test-framework.html).

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class CustomReaderTest extends JerseyTest {

    private static final String DATA = "UselessStaticData";
    private static final String CUSTOM_MEDIA_TYPE = "application/useless";

    @Consumes(CUSTOM_MEDIA_TYPE)
    public static class UselessReader implements MessageBodyReader<String> {

        @Override
        public boolean isReadable(Class<?> aClass, Type type,
                                  Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String readFrom(Class<String> aClass, Type type, Annotation[] annotations,
                               MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String,String> multivaluedMap,
                               InputStream inputStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            return DATA;
        }
    }


    @Path("test")
    public static class TestResource {

        @GET
        @Produces(CUSTOM_MEDIA_TYPE)
        public InputStream post(String data) {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream("Test".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig()
                .register(TestResource.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIt() {
        Response res = target("test")
                .register(UselessReader.class)
                .request(CUSTOM_MEDIA_TYPE)
                .get();

        assertThat(res.readEntity(String.class)).isEqualTo(DATA);
    }
}
```